# Session::put not working when i put die or exit after declaration in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

I am facing one issue. I am using Laravel 5.2 and i have put some data in session. After that I have kept `die` and session can't be accessed in another function. But when i remove `die` it is running fine. But I want to store data in session even i keep `die`.

Here is my code:

```
public function session_test(Request $request){
    $test = "live"
    Session::put('filterdata',$test);
    die;
}

public function session_get(Request $request){
    echo Session::get('filterdata');
}
```

Please help me in figuring out the issue.

Comment: does `session_get` called after `session_test` ??

Comment: session_test function is declared first and after that session_get

Comment: did you try to get `session` just before die?? or try exit !!

Comment: you can use session table for that?

Comment: @MeeraTank i have tried but not working

Comment: @Mr.Pyramid no this is not right idea.

Comment: ok you are not getting session just before die??

Comment: @kunal it means it's not setting that's why you are not getting it

Comment: i am getting session before die but when i put die it is not accessed in another function

Comment: @MeeraTank i am getting session before die but not in another function

Comment: you can use exit in place of die i think.

Comment: already done but not working

Comment: how about `return true;` ?

Comment: Mm.. yeah you can use `return true;`??

Comment: but return true doesn't stop the execuion

Comment: there is nothing after that statement!! nothing will execute!

Comment: i want to execution to be stopped and put data in session

Comment: @MeeraTank i have tried but not working

Comment: finally i have done that with this command return response()->json($records);

Comment: post as an answer in an appropriate way

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem in my one of functionality.
I have solved after lot of hour using checking some laravel documentation about session.

You can do use this function before exit or die function when you have to use Session::put, Session::remove, Session::forget

```
public function session_test(Request $request){
 $test = "live"
 Session::put('filterdata',$test);
 Session::save();
 die;
}
public function session_get(Request $request){
 echo Session::get('filterdata');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to remove session variable use this way.

```
public function session_test(Request $request){
    $test = "live"
    Session::put('filterdata',$test);    
}

public function session_get(Request $request){
    echo Session::get('filterdata');
    Session::forget('filterdata');
}
```

Comment: no wrong way i don't want to forget session at all i want to add  die; in session_test function only

Comment: Why should have you use die functions.

Comment: i am using datatables so need that type of functionality

Comment: Okay you have using data table, then why should need die functions.I think your  going wrong way.

Comment: i am using metronic theme with databales